# How to checked radio button in Vue.js using V-Model?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

Im new to laravel and vue.js. I'm developing a simple online examination and Im having a hard time in showing the answer of the user if he/she will click the previous button.

This my template I used v-for to loop the questions:

```
 <div class="myQuestion" v-for="(question, index) in questions" :key="index + uuid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <blockquote >
            Total Questions &nbsp;&nbsp;{{ index+1 }} / {{questions.length}}
          </blockquote>
          <h2 class="question">Q. &nbsp;{{question.question}}</h2>
          <form class="myForm" action="/quiz_start" v-on:submit.prevent="createQuestion(question.question_id, question.answer, auth.id, question.topic_id)" method="post">
            <input class="radioBtn" v-bind:id="'radio'+ index" type="radio" v-model="result.user_answer" value="A" aria-checked="false" > <span>{{question.a}}</span><br>
            <input class="radioBtn" v-bind:id="'radio'+ index+1" type="radio" v-model="result.user_answer" value="B" aria-checked="false"> <span>{{question.b}}</span><br>
            <input class="radioBtn" v-bind:id="'radio'+ index+2" type="radio" v-model="result.user_answer" value="C" aria-checked="false"> <span>{{question.c}}</span><br>
            <input class="radioBtn" v-bind:id="'radio'+ index+3" type="radio" v-model="result.user_answer" value="D" aria-checked="false"> <span>{{question.d}}</span><br>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-8">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-wave btn-block nextbtn">Next</button>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-8">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-wave btn-block prebtn">Previous</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
```

This is my script to fetch the data and insert the data array to questions variable.

```
<script>
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
export default {

  props: ['topic_id'],

  data () {
    return {
      questions: [],
      answers: [],
      uuid:0,
      result: {
        question_id: '',
        answer: '',
        user_id: '',
        user_answer:0,
        topic_id: '',
      },
      auth: [],
    }
  },

  created () {
    this.fetchQuestions();
  },

  methods: {

    fetchQuestions() {
      this.$http.get(`${this.$props.topic_id}/quiz/${this.$props.topic_id}`).then(response => {
        this.questions = response.data.questions;
        this.auth = response.data.auth;
        this.uuid=uuidv4();
        console.log(this.questions);
      }).catch((e) => {
        console.log(e)
      });
    },

    createQuestion(id, ans, user_id, topic_id) {
      this.result.question_id = id;
      this.result.answer = ans;
      this.result.user_id = user_id;
      this.result.topic_id = this.$props.topic_id;
      this.$http.post(`${this.$props.topic_id}/quiz`, this.result).then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data.message);
        let newdata=response.data.newdata;
        this.questions.splice(newdata[0]["index"],1,newdata[0]);
      }).catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
      });
      this.result.topic_id = '';
      this.result.user_answer =0;
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I used jQuery next() and prev() for the next and previous buttons. In questions variable, I store my array of objects from database which contains the questions and choices so after the user click next it will update the element of questions to insert the answer chosen by the user. My problem is how can I checked the answer by default chosen by the user if the question showed was answered already by the user. This is the time when the user wants to review his/her answers before finishing the exam.

Comment: Welcome to SO .. have you done any research ? https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Checkbox

Comment: yes but didn't find anything solution for this, is there a way to set variable value inside v-for loop? update like this.result.user_answer = new value

Comment: `user_answer` this should be array and if you put selected value then it will be automatically selected

Comment: What I did is that my questions array contain the user answer, so all i want is to checked the radio button if the user browse to previous question which he already answered and checked his answer as default, so what i want is to assign this.result.user_answer = question.user_answer